# Google Analytics API v3 can't retrieve data for an user admin, not an owner

Tags: .net, google-analytics-api

We're trying to get a list of all google account profile from a single administrator user with google analytics api v3.

We've got a user (admin@company.com) that is an administrator for multiple account of multiple domain but not an owner of any of them and has no personal analytics account.

1. We create a new console project.
2. Create the remote services in google console like suggested in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api#auth) with our user admin@company.com
3. Import dll from nuget packages.
4. Wrote this simple code to test the connection and get a profile list of our user following [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Account_%28available_only_on_.NET_framework_4%29).

   public class Program
   {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       // privatekey.p12 has been downloaded and referred with path
       var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"privatekey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

   ```
   // this email was provided by google service account
   var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                        {
                          Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly },
                          // this is the name of one profile account admin
                          User = "name"
                        }.FromCertificate(certificate);

   // Create the service.
   var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {
     HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer),
     // this is our application name on google service account
     ApplicationName = "app name",
   });

   var services = service.Management.Profiles.List("~all", "~all").Execute();
   ```

   }
   }

When we're trying to get profile list, we get this error

```
Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:"" ..
```

Any help appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the NTP time.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization
Section "Troubleshooting"

Answer (score 1):

You cant query the Profiles directly. You need to go though Account -> web Property then -> profile

// get the accounts

```
ManagementResource.AccountsResource.ListRequest AccountListRequest = service.Management.Accounts.List();
Accounts AccountList = AccountListRequest.Execute();
```

// find the account you want

```
Account Daimto = AccountList.Items.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower().Contains("daimto")).First();
```

// get the web properties for that account

```
service.Management.Webproperties.List(Daimto.Id);
Webproperties WebPropertyList = WebPropertyListRequest.Execute();
```

// find the web property you want

```
Webproperty DaimtoWP = WebPropertyList.Items.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower().Contains("daimto")).First();
```

// get the profiles for that webproperty

```
ManagementResource.ProfilesResource.ListRequest ProfileListRequest = service.Management.Profiles.List(Daimto.Id,DaimtoWP.Id);
Profiles ProfileList = ProfileListRequest.Execute();
```

This is all copyed from my blog post: http://daimto.com/google-analytics-api-v3-with-c/